# How to check if there are 5 checkboxes or 6 in an image slice?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have two types of slices, one has 6 checkboxes and the other has 5.

1. [image: Slice with 6 checkboxes]
2. [image: Slice with 5 checkboxes]

You can check out the [complete dataset here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzw2E.jpg)

**My approach ( doesn't work well )**

I took the mean of the images using `np.mean(image)` and put up a threshold value (140) such that if the value if greater that that, then the image has six checkboxes else it has five. The idea behind this approach is that, in my opinion, the slice with six checkboxes have more black pixels than the one with five.

**Question**

So, my question is, what else can I go so that I can get an accurate classification? I am using Python 3.6 and OpenCV, so some solutions using these would be appreciated.

Optionally, although I don't have the sort of data to run a deep learning process on. I am interested to know if deep learning can help here as well.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention this, I also tried to find the contours and shapes ( squares & rectangles ), but they are not consistent, because of the low resolution and since the boxes might have tick marks on it too. I get 2-3 boxes for both, but that is not enough to tell me the difference

Comment: Did you try detecting boxes? That doesn't look too difficult...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry, forgot to mention it. I tried detecting the boxes too, but they are not consistent, because of the low resolution and since the boxes might have tick marks on it too. I get 2-3 boxes for both, but that is not enough to tell me the difference

Comment: Can you do something about the quality of your input images? I mean, some of the scans are quite bad (there are some odd dark areas in few, and several are poorly cropped). Having an inconsistent/low quality input will make it much harder to develop a good solution.

Comment: @DanMašek Unfortunately no, this is the challenge.

Comment: A teaser: https://imgur.com/a/nuOPxmL https://pastebin.com/8MEjCK4a :) Now I have to write up an answer to explain it all :D Please, be patient. | For a while I played with using convolution (`filter2D`)  with kernels that promoted the edges of the box and suppressed the center of it... I could see the boxes on the results in most of the cases, but it was really hard to pick them up programmatically. Eventually I converged on this approach, that tries to look for the vertical edges of those boxes. They are generally in fixed positions, which differ between the 5 and 6 box configuration.

Comment: BTW, I renamed you sample files, so that all the numbers are 2 digit, with 0 padding -- that was so they sort in the proper order. Let me know what you think :)

Comment: @DanMašek WOW! This looks awesome. I was about to put a bounty on the question, and I'll still do it for your answer. Looking forward to it.

Comment: There you go, please comment. I'm gonna go sleep now, this was fun, thanks for the excercise :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*After a couple of unsuccessful attempts, the following approach seems to yield satisfactory results on the provided input dataset.*

---

### Prelude

On first inspection, I noticed all the sample images were of the same shape, so I could stack them easily. I began with observing the image containing all the input images stacked vertically (using [`numpy.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html))

[image: All input images vertically stacked]

I made the following observations:

- All the images (and check-boxes) are at similar scale
- There are 2 kinds of layout (5 boxes, 6 boxes) and the locations of the check-boxes rarely overlap (good criterion)
- For each kind of layout, the check-boxes are roughly in the same place
- The vertical edges of each check-box seem to be the most prominent features

Playing with an image editor, I determined that the following masks are a good estimate of the location of the check-boxes:

- 5 boxes: [image: Mask for 5 boxes]
- 6 boxes: [image: Mask for 6 boxes]

or, in Python code, showing pairs of first/last column for each region:

```
# Define the zones (x axis ranges) where checkboxes may occur
zones_a = [(50, 72), (144, 166), (243, 265), (328, 350), (436, 458)] # 5 box scenario
zones_b = [(42,  64), (122, 144), (207, 229), (276, 298), (369, 391), (496, 518)] # 6 box scanario
```

---

With that in mind I arrived at the following approach:

- Minimize any noise (some if the input images are quite bad)
- Try to emphasize the vertical checkbox lines while eliminating as much of the rest as possible
- Find where the vertical lines are clustered
- Find the pattern they correspond to better

---

### Proprocessing

For demonstration, I'll go with one of the nasty ones:

[image: Nastiest sample input]

First, I read it as a grayscale image

```
img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

and binarize it -- [adaptive threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3) with a fairly large block size seems to do a good job at removing much of the noise while preserving the relevant details (even though in this case there's still a lot of undesirable junk left)

```
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2)
```

**NB:** Since at this point, we're working with black text on white, the meanings of `erode` and `dilate` are reversed -- erode expands the black parts, dilate reduces them. *(It's intuitive once you grok the topic)*

Next, I try to emphasize vertical edges using morphological operations

```
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, np.ones((1,3),np.uint8))
```

and then de-emphasize the horizontal edges (including majority of the text as well)

```
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((3,1),np.uint8))
```

As the next step, I use the [Canny edge detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) to find all the edges

```
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 40, 120, apertureSize=5)
```

**NB:** Now the edges are white and rest is black, so morphological operations work as [naively] expected. *(Again, it's intuitive once you grok the topic)*

Now I do a morphological opening, in ordeer to eliminate horizontal edges (that are now generally single pixel lines), while preserving the vertical edges.

```
edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((5,1),np.uint8))
```

And I follow that by emphasizing the vertical edges using dilation

```
edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((1,3),np.uint8))
```

---

[image: Intermediate images]

---

### Analysis

Upon examination of the preprocessed image, I noticed that where check-boxes were present, there were many columns containing majority of white pixels, while elsewhere this was not so.

I used a technique called "vertical projection" to reduce the 2-dimensional image to 1 dimension, by taking a mean intensity of each column.

```
projection = np.mean(edges, 0).flatten()
```

smoothed it using a mean filter roughly as wide as each potential checkbox location

```
projection = cv2.blur(projection, (1, 21)).flatten()
```

and then smoothed it again at half-span

```
projection = cv2.blur(projection, (1, 11)).flatten()
```

The final `projection` curve now had prominent peaks where the check-boxes were located.

The following graph shows the results of this processing (yellow=original, red=pass1, blue=pass2).

[image: vertical projections]

The next step was to find the peaks in this curve -- [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) turned out to give desired results.

```
peaks = find_peaks(projection)[0]
```

Since more than one peak could potentially occur within region of a box, I decided to store associated values for each peak (for later discrimination)

```
peak_values = projection[peaks]
```

---

Now I could generate a nice graph to visualize the likely locations of check-boxes, along with the detected peaks as well as the ranges where the check-boxes are expected to be in the two scenarios.

[image: Smoothed projection, peaks and zones]

In this graph:

- blue curve is the smoothed vertical projection
- vertical purple lines show detected peaks
- faint yellow and red areas show where check-boxes may occur
  ** yellow if there are 5 present
  ** red if there are 6 present

---

At this point I knew the places where check-boxes were likely to be (peak location), along with an indicator of how likely this is to be (the value at the peak). This was enough to decide on which scenario is a better fit.

First step was to "bin the peaks". For each scenario, there was a set of ranges, each range specifying the minimum and maximum X coordinate. I used the following function to collect the peaks for each potential check-box location:

```
def bin_peaks(peaks, values, zones):
    bins = [[] for x in xrange(len(zones))]

    for peak, value in zip(peaks, values):
        for i, zone in enumerate(zones):
            if (peak >= zone[0]) and (peak <= zone[1]):
                bins[i].append((peak, value))

    return bins
```

At this point, for each potential check-box location, I had list of 0 or more peaks that corresponded to it.

---

To be able to decide which of the two scenarios was a better fit, I needed to reduce things to single floating point values representing quality of the match. Simple rules -- scenario with higher quality indicator wins.

As a starting point, I chose to use the sum of weights for each position, normalized to the number of positions.

For each position there were 3 possibilities:

- no peaks in the region -- weight 0.0
- single peak in the region -- weight = peak value
- more than one peaks in the region -- weight = max peak value

In code:

```
def analyze_bins(bins):
    total_weight = 0.0
    for i, bin in enumerate(bins):
        weight = 0.0
        if len(bin) > 0:
            best_bin = sorted(bin, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
            weight = best_bin[1]

        total_weight += weight

    total_weight /= len(bins)
    return total_weight
```

Debug output of this algorithm for each scenario:

[image]

---

At this point I had a single metric for each scenario and the decision was simple -- the higher one was the winner.

```
weight_a = analyze_bins(bins_a)
weight_b = analyze_bins(bins_b)

checkbox_count = 5 if (weight_a > weight_b) else 6
```

[image: Result]

---

### Conclusion

[Album of report images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L1aY.jpg)

And a image summarizing results for all sample inputs:

[image]

---

Full script producing all the reports:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import math

import StringIO

from scipy.signal import find_peaks

# ============================================================================

# Define the zones (x axis ranges) where checkboxes may occur
zones_a = [(50, 72), (144, 166), (243, 265), (328, 350), (436, 458)] # 5 box scenario
zones_b = [(42,  64), (122, 144), (207, 229), (276, 298), (369, 391), (496, 518)] # 6 box scanario

# ============================================================================

# Bonus -- plot a detailed analysis report as a PNG image
def plot_report(filename, report):
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

    IMAGE_KEYS = ['img', 'thresh', 'thresh_1', 'thresh_2', 'canny', 'canny_1', 'canny_2']
    PLOT_SPAN = 5
    TEXT_SPAN = 2
    ROW_COUNT = (len(IMAGE_KEYS) + 1) + 3 * (PLOT_SPAN + 1) + 2 * (TEXT_SPAN)

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.suptitle(filename)
    gs = GridSpec(ROW_COUNT, 2)

    row = 0

    for key in IMAGE_KEYS:
        plt.subplot(gs[row,:])
        plt.gca().set_title(key)
        plt.imshow(report[key], cmap='gray', aspect='equal')
        plt.axis('off')
        row += 1

    proj_width = len(report['projection'])
    proj_x = np.arange(proj_width)

    plt.subplot(gs[row+1:row+1+PLOT_SPAN,:])
    plt.gca().set_title('Vertical Projections (Raw and Smoothed)')
    plt.plot(proj_x, report['projection'], 'y-')
    plt.plot(proj_x, report['projection_1'], 'r-')
    plt.plot(proj_x, report['projection_2'], 'b-')
    plt.xlim((0, proj_width - 1))
    plt.ylim((0, 255))

    row += PLOT_SPAN + 1

    plt.subplot(gs[row+1:row+1+PLOT_SPAN,:])
    plt.gca().set_title('Smoothed Projection with Peaks and Zones')
    plt.plot(proj_x, report['projection_2'])

    for zone in zones_a:
        plt.axvspan(zone[0], zone[1], facecolor='y', alpha=0.1)
    for zone in zones_b:
        plt.axvspan(zone[0], zone[1], facecolor='r', alpha=0.1)
    for x in report['peaks']:
        plt.axvline(x=x, color='m')

    plt.xlim((0, proj_width - 1))
    plt.ylim((0, report['projection_2'].max()))

    row += PLOT_SPAN + 1

    plt.subplot(gs[row+1:row+1+TEXT_SPAN,0], frameon=False)
    plt.gca().set_title('Details - 5 boxes')
    plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
    plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.text(0, 1, report['details_a'], family='monospace', fontsize=8, ha='left', va='top')

    plt.subplot(gs[row+1:row+1+TEXT_SPAN,1], frameon=False)
    plt.gca().set_title('Details - 6 boxes')
    plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
    plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.text(0, 1, report['details_b'], family='monospace', fontsize=8, ha='left', va='top')

    row += TEXT_SPAN

    plt.subplot(gs[row+1:row+1+PLOT_SPAN,:])
    plt.gca().set_title('Weights')
    plt.barh([2, 1]
        , [report['weight_a'], report['weight_b']]
        , align='center'
        , color=['y', 'r']
        , tick_label=['5 boxes', '6 boxes'])
    plt.ylim((0.5, 2.5))

    row += PLOT_SPAN + 1
    row += 1

    plt.subplot(gs[row,:])
    plt.gca().set_title('Input Image')
    plt.imshow(report['img'], cmap='gray', aspect='equal')
    plt.axis('off')

    row += 1

    plt.subplot(gs[row:row+TEXT_SPAN,:], frameon=False)
    plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
    plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    result_text = "The image contains %d boxes." % report['checkbox_count']
    plt.text(0.5, 1, result_text, family='monospace', weight='semibold', fontsize=24, ha='center', va='top')

    fig.set_size_inches(12, ROW_COUNT * 0.8)
    plt.savefig('plot_%s.png' % filename[:2], bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close(fig)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Bonus - create summary image showing inputs along with coloured result annotations.
def summary_report(result):
    ROW_HEIGHT = result[0][0].shape[0]
    images = [i[0] for i in result]
    stacked = np.vstack(images)
    extended = cv2.copyMakeBorder(stacked, 0, 0, 80, 0, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    result = cv2.cvtColor(extended, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    for i, entry in enumerate(result):
        cv2.putText(result, '%d boxes' % entry[0]
            , (4, ROW_HEIGHT * (i+1) - 4)
            , cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            , 0.5
            , [(0, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255)][entry[0] - 5]
            , 1)
    return result

# ============================================================================

# Collect peaks that fall into each potential checkbox location
def bin_peaks(peaks, values, zones):
    bins = [[] for x in xrange(len(zones))]

    for peak, value in zip(peaks, values):
        for i, zone in enumerate(zones):
            if (peak >= zone[0]) and (peak <= zone[1]):
                bins[i].append((peak, value))

    return bins

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Select best peaks for each bin, weigh them and return total weight + details text
def analyze_bins(bins):
    buf = StringIO.StringIO()

    total_weight = 0.0
    for i, bin in enumerate(bins):
        buf.write("Position %d: " % i)
        weight = 0.0
        if len(bin) == 0:
            buf.write("no peaks")
        else:
            best_bin = sorted(bin, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
            weight = best_bin[1]
            if len(bin) == 1:
                buf.write("single peak @ %d (value=%0.3f)" % best_bin)
            else:
                buf.write("%d peaks, best @ %d (value=%0.3f)" % (len(bin), best_bin[0], best_bin[1]))

        buf.write(" | weight=%0.3f\n" % weight)

        total_weight += weight

    total_weight /= len(bins)
    buf.write("Total weight = %0.3f" % total_weight)
    return total_weight, buf.getvalue()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Process an input image, return checkbox count along with detailed debugging info in a dict
def process_image(filename):
    report = {}

    img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    report['img'] = img.copy()

    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2)
    report['thresh'] = thresh.copy()

    thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, np.ones((1,3),np.uint8))
    report['thresh_1'] = thresh.copy()

    thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((3,1),np.uint8))
    report['thresh_2'] = thresh.copy()

    edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 40, 120, apertureSize=5)
    report['canny'] = edges.copy()

    edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((5,1),np.uint8))
    report['canny_1'] = edges.copy()

    edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((1,3),np.uint8))
    report['canny_2'] = edges.copy()

    projection = np.mean(edges, 0).flatten()
    report['projection'] = projection.copy()

    projection = cv2.blur(projection, (1, 21)).flatten()
    report['projection_1'] = projection.copy()

    projection = cv2.blur(projection, (1, 11)).flatten()
    report['projection_2'] = projection.copy()

    peaks = find_peaks(projection)[0]
    report['peaks'] = peaks.copy()

    peak_values = projection[peaks]
    report['peak_values'] = peak_values.copy()

    bins_a = bin_peaks(peaks, peak_values, zones_a)
    report['bins_a'] = list(bins_a)

    bins_b = bin_peaks(peaks, peak_values, zones_b)
    report['bins_b'] = list(bins_b)

    weight_a, details_a = analyze_bins(bins_a)
    report['weight_a'] = weight_a
    report['details_a'] = details_a
    weight_b, details_b = analyze_bins(bins_b)
    report['weight_b'] = weight_b
    report['details_b'] = details_b

    checkbox_count = 5 if (weight_a > weight_b) else 6
    report['checkbox_count'] = checkbox_count

    return checkbox_count, report

# ============================================================================

result = []
for filename in glob.glob('*-*.png'):
    box_count, report = process_image(filename)
    plot_report(filename, report)
    result.append((report['img'], report['checkbox_count']))

cv2.imwrite('summary.png', summary_report(result))
```

---

*Feel free to correct any typos, and let me know about anything that needs to be clarified.*

Comment: Thank you so much. This is much appreciated. This has been such a bottleneck for me. If this works, I owe you lunch :D

Comment: Update, this worked very well. Thanks a lot. It gave about 89% accuracy on the complete dataset.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog Nice. It would be interesting to see some of the cases where it failed.

Comment: I'll share a sample today. Thanks

Comment: Hi Dan, is there an equivalent of the scipy method `find_peaks` that you have used? Actually I am using AWS Lambda and the package scipy takes up a lot of space because of which it exceeds the limits (250MB).

Answer (score 1):

This should help you https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Essentially it boils down to finding the contours in the image then using `cv2.approxPolyDP` to figure out how many sides there are to the shape. Then just check for how many 4 sided shapes you have.

You will probably get one for the outer box, but you can just check for boxes with no other boxes inside of them to isolate your checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it. I tried detecting the boxes too, but they are not consistent, because of the low resolution and since the boxes might have tick marks on it too. I get 2-3 boxes for both, but that is not enough to tell me the difference

Comment: Huh, that is tough. You could try an edge map first, to try to correct slightly for the blurriness caused by low resolution. As for the ticks nothing springs immediately to mind besides machine learning, which seems like overkill. Maybe go the other way, have a set of boxes and try to fit as many as you can into the image? I'll give it a bit more thought